# How to print a file if a line contains a specific string in python?

Tags: regular-expression, python, python3

I'm trying to print a file name if it contains an `**Error***` (here, * says there can be anything such as `Rock_Error_addr`, `Error_salary`,       `TinaError_addr` (it may have spaces also in the beginning)). I can be able to print if I use the exact string using regex. but confused a bit confused about how to use it in the above case.

```
with open ('input.txt', 'r') as i:
    for line in i:
        a = re.search ('Error_salary', line) #I also tried a=re.search ('\s+Error\w+', line)
        print (line)
```

From the above code, I can print only that specific string...I wanted to print any thing that contains Error. Any help would be aprreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47685206/reading-rpt-files-with-pandas

Comment: @ajgringo619 I tried it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you execute a `for` loop over a string, you will iterate over each character in the string:

```
>>> glob.glob( '*.rpt' )
['test.rpt']
>>> for i in 'test.rpt':
...  print i
...
t
e
s
t
.
r
p
t
```

This seems to work:

```
import glob
with open( 'output.txt', 'w' ) as w:
   for file in glob.glob( '*.rpt' ):
      with open( file, 'r' ) as r:
         w.writelines( r.readlines() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modifying a little your `python` code and making an `if`+`break` as soon as the error string is detected in a line read in.

```
import re
with open('input.txt', 'r') as i:
    for line in i:
        if re.search(r'Error', line):
            print('input.txt')
            break
```

But you don't need the regex here as you only need to look for a literal string Error.

```
if 'Error' in line:
```

will work just as well.